# "Required request part 'image' is not present in" error in springboot with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

When i try to upload a image in react, and send it to a spring boot api to save the file in a database, I get the following errors in spring boot:

```
2022-12-04 03:25:28.610  WARN 15080 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'image' is not present]
2022-12-04 03:25:28.631  WARN 15080 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

Idk how to solve this. I've tried searching around, but havent found any answer. Im also unsure if the problem is in my react code or in my springboot code.

I think my error is in reactjs, because ive seen in other posts for people have somewhat the same problem, that their problem has been their react code. But I havent figured out what exactly might be wrong with my react code. Im also posting my spring boot code in case you may want to look at it,
My react code:

```
const FileUpload = () => {



    const link = "http://localhost:8080/uploadimage?key"

    var formData = new FormData()

    const [fileName, setFilename] = useState("")

    const [tags, setTags] = useState([])






    {/* THIS IS CODE FOR SELECTING A FILE TO UPLOAD*/}
    {/* IM TRYING TO DEFINE IMAGE BY PUTTING IT IN QUOTES IN FROMDATA.APPEND */}
    const handleFile = (e) => {
        setFilename(e.target.files[0].name)
        console.log("handle file")
        console.log(e.target.files[0])
        formData.append("image", e.target.files[0])

    }



    const uploadFile = (e) => {
    {/* THIS IS CODE FOR FILE UPLOADING*/}
        console.log("sending...")
        console.log(formData)
        axios.post(
            link, 
            formData, {
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })



    {/* THIS IS CODE FOR SOMETHING ELSE; SOME TAGHANDLING */}
       setTimeout(3000)
        const taglink = "http://localhost:8080/givetags/" + fileName;
        axios.post(taglink, tags)
        .then(res => (
            console.log(res.data)
            ))
           
    }


    {/* THIS IS CODE IS ALSO FOR SOMETHING ELSE*/}
    function updateTags(e) {
        const log = {...tags}
        log[e.target.id] = e.target.value.split(" ")
        setTags(log)
    }





  return (
    <div>

        <Container>
            <Card.Title className='text-center mb-3'>Upload File</Card.Title>
            <Form.Group controlId='file' className='mb-3'>
                <Form.Control type='file' onChange={(e) => handleFile(e)}></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId='tags' className='mb-3'>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => updateTags(e)} type="text" placeholder='Write tags'></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button onClick={(e) => uploadFile(e)}>Upload File</Button>
        </Container>

        <TagsConvention></TagsConvention>





    </div>
  )
}

export default FileUpload
```

This is my springboot code:
Controller:

```
@RestController
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageServiceImpl service;

//==========================For uploading a file======================================
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/uploadimage")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String uploadImage = service.uploadImage(file);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(uploadImage);
    }




    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/getimage/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadImage(@PathVariable String fileName){


        byte[] file=service.downloadImage(fileName);
        System.out.println(file);



        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(service.getType(fileName)))
                .body(file);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/givetags/{fileName}")
    public ImageData giveImagetags(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> tags) {
        //return service.giveImageTags(fileName, tags);
        //return service.giveImageTags(fileName, tags);

        System.out.println(tags);
        List<String> tagList = tags.get("tags");


        return service.giveImageTags(fileName, tagList);


    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/getallimages")
    public List<String> getAllImages() {
        return service.getAllImages();
    }





}
```

My model for the image:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ImageData")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ImageData implements Image{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long imageDataId;

    private String name;
    private String type;




    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="file_has_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="image_data_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("image_data")
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image_data",length = 1000)
    private byte[] data;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageData{" +
                "imageDataId=" + imageDataId +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", tags=" + tags +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service function for uploading a file:

```
public String uploadImage(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    ImageData imageData = imageDataRepository.save(ImageData.builder()
            .name(file.getOriginalFilename())
            .type(file.getContentType())
            .data(ImageUtils.compressImage(file.getBytes())).build()); //"data" is from the model class

    System.out.println(imageData.toString());
    if (imageData != null) {
        return "file uploaded successfully : " + file.getOriginalFilename();
    }
    return null;
}
```

functions in utils class for compressing image

```
public static byte[] compressImage(byte[] data) {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    deflater.setInput(data);
    deflater.finish();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] tmp = new byte[4*1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int size = deflater.deflate(tmp);
        outputStream.write(tmp, 0, size);
    }
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Ive tried to change the value of formdata, and the key in "image" in fromdata.append, but I havent figured it out. Ive also tried to search up the problem, but people have had different syntax problems from me, so idk what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions:

(1)Required request part 'image' is not present, the problem should be the parameter name problem, The @RequestParam("image") prefix must be "image". You can check if some parameter names are image.

(2)JSON parse error: In my opinion, the main cause of the problem is the API: givetags, @RequestBody Map<String, List> tags, which is not translated properly when receiving the react parameter. You can try using List to receive arguments.